# WCF Data Services (OData) Generated Online Help & Documentation

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata

With ASP.NET MVC 4.0 WebApi you get very nice auto-generated help for the API, similar to what used to be generated with ASMX web services and also can be configured for WCF, see link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230442.aspx

Does this work for, or is there an equivalent for OData endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

There is no official equivalent at this point, at least AFAIK.  You would need to parse the CSDL model generated from the `$metadata` resource to make it ready for human consumption.

It's not entirely related, but if I remember the preview specs for OData v4.0 correctly, the metadata itself will be accessible as an OData endpoint (a bit like database catalogs in most DBMS are accessible through tables themselves).  You would then be able to use any OData explorer to browse the API metadata.